# Object refrence error in Parent / Child Relationship class structure

Tags: c#

I have following code snippet in c#

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        PhoneList = new List<PhoneNumber>();
    }
    public Customer(int id, string name)
    {
        this.CustomerID = id;
        this.CustomerName = name;
    }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneList { get; set; }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber()
    {
    }
    public PhoneNumber(int id, int number)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Number = number;

    }
}
```

I am using these classes in UI as bellow

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

        list.Add(new Customer(2, "John"));
        list.Add(new Customer(3, "Joe"));
        list.Add(new Customer(4, "Don"));
        **list[0].PhoneList.Add(new PhoneNumber(1, 1231213));//Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
        list[0].PhoneList.Add(new PhoneNumber(1, 1231213));
        GridView1.DataSource = list;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

When I am executing the page getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you create `Customer.PhoneList` in `Customer`'s default constructor you don't create it in the id/name constructor. Either add

```
PhoneList = new List<PhoneNumber>();
```

to the second constructor, or chain the constructors with `this()` syntax:

```
public Customer(int id, string name) : this()
{
    this.CustomerID = id;
    this.CustomerName = name;
}
```

which will call the default constructor first.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the constructors in `Customer` needs to initialise the `PhoneList` collection. You're calling the constructor override that takes `Id` and `Name` and it doesn't initialise the collection. Change that constructor as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        PhoneList = new List<PhoneNumber>();
    }
    public Customer(int id, string name)
        : this()
    {
        this.CustomerID = id;
        this.CustomerName = name;
    }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising PhoneList in the `Customer(int id, string name)` constructor, it is therefore null when you add new customers.

Answer (score 0):

null is the default value for reference types. Because you don't initialize your PhoneList before it's usage, it remains to be null and you get this exception

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered initializing PhoneList property in your constructor with parameters? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
public Customer(int id, string name) : this()     
{         
  this.CustomerID = id;         
  this.CustomerName = name;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Customer(int id, string name)
    {
        PhoneList = new List<PhoneNumber>(); //this constructor is call
        this.CustomerID = id;
        this.CustomerName = name;
    }
```

You did not add PhoneList in the **other constructor** which is being called in your code, So its never initialised